# How to count the leaves of a tree in prolog?

Tags: tree, prolog

I am trying to sum the leaves of a tree and cannot seem to do it correctly any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried several different methods and none seem to work right.

```
nleaves(nil, 0).
nleaves(node(_,Left,Right), N) :- 
    nleaves(Left, N1),
    nleaves(Right, N2),
    N is N1 + N2.
```

when I ask the query `?- nleaves(3, node(1, node(2, node(3, nil, nil), node(4, nil, nil)), node(5,nil,nil)), N).`, it comes back with
`N = 0`. Now, if I replace `0` with `1` in the base case and ask the same query, it returns `N = 6`. Then if I completely manipulate the predicate which is completely wrong and not acceptable

```
nleaves(nil, 0).
nleaves(node(_, Left, Right), N) :- 
    nleaves(Left, LN), 
    nleaves(Right, RN),
    N is 3 - LN + RN.
```

It will then spit out `N = 3`.

What can I do to this to make it say `N = 3` the right way? I am at a loss for counting the leaves. I seem to be able to count the height correctly with a max predicate helper.

```
height(nil, 0). % base case empty tree height is 0.
height(node(_,Left,Right), N) :- 
    height(Left, LN), 
    height(Right, RN),
    N is max(LN, RN) + 1.
```

but I cannot figure out how to count the leaves.

Comment: The fact that it returns `0` for the first one is not that strange, for `nil` you say `0`, and for a node, you add the two up, so eventually you are only adding up zeros, and this is equal to zero.

Comment: Why then when I change the 0 to a 1 does it spit out 6? Sorry very new to prolog and I am really trying to understand how to count the leaves. I have also tried other methods that will spit out 15 which is the size of the tree, but cannot seem to wrap my head around the counting of leaves.

Comment: because for a `nleaves(3,node(1, node(2, node(3,nil,nil),node(4,nil,nil)), node(5,nil,nil)),N).`, there are six `nil`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base predicate should be *one* for a leaf, and `0` for a `nil`, so:

```
nleaves(nil, 0).
nleaves(node(_, nil, nil), 1).
nleaves(node(_, Left, Right), N) :-
    (dif(Left, nil); dif(Right, nil)),
    nleaves(Left, L),
    nleaves(Right, R),
    N is L + R.
```

Here the second clause thus counts a leaf `node(_, nil, nil)` as one, and a node where at least one of the two items is not `nil` as the sum of the leaves of the two nodes.

Comment: TY so much this helps me understand what was going on with the N=6. and how to accomplish this goal!!!

Comment: @Zasha: you can accept this answer from Willem by clicking the grey checkmark below the upvote/downvote buttons left to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

So a leaf is a node pointing to 2 nils, right?

```
nleaves(nil,0).
nleaves(node(_,nil,nil),1).
nleaves(node(_,Left,Right),N):- 
    dif((Left,Right), (nil,nil)),
    nleaves(Left,N1),
    nleaves(Right,N2),
    N is N1+N2.
```

Comment: This will not work for `node(2, nil, node(3, nil, nil))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange definition of a tree; the more normal definition has a type that looks like this:

```
leaf(Value)
node(Left, Right)
```

Then you can traverse it like this (I'm using DCG notation -- if you don't understand what's going on, do the query `listing(preorder)` to see the code expansion):

```
preorder(leaf(Value)) --> [Value].
preorder(node(Left, Right)) -->
    preorder(Left),
    preorder(Right).

%           *
%         /  \
%       1
%           /  \
%               4
%         / \
%        2   3

test(Values) :-
    phrase(preorder(
                    node(leaf(1),
                         node(node(leaf(2), leaf(3)),
                              leaf(4)))),
           Values).
```

```
?- test(V).
V = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

If you want to know how many leaves, just use the `length/2` predicate on `Values`. Or you can modify the accumulator to do the arithmetic:

```
count_leaves(Tree, Count) :-
    count_leaves(Tree, 0, Count).

count_leaves(leaf(_), Count0, Count) :-
    Count is Count0 + 1.
count_leaves(node(Left, Right), Count0, Count) :-
    count_leaves(Left, Count0, Count1),
    count_leaves(Right, Count1, Count).
```